Sphinx autodoc - Skipping members with automethod set
I'm using sphinx and a few of the files have the directive .. automethod:: set. I need a way to have sphinx show all __init__ methods, without removing the .. automethod:: directive and without any warnings. I tried to look through stack, but didn't see anything like this. Here's a MWE:
class A():
    """
    documentation

    .. automethod:: __init__
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        documentation for A
        """

class B:
    """
    documentation

    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        documentation for B
        """

def skip_member(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    // What do I put here to skip the __init__ of class A, but *not* the __init__ of class B?
    if name == '__init__':
        return False
    return skip

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', skip_member)

With this I get the following error:
/home/xxx/sphinx-test/classFile.py:docstring of classFile.A.__init__:1: WARNING: duplicate object description of classFile.A.__init__, other instance in usage, use :no-index: for one of them

I want to be able to get rid of this error message without removing the .. automethod:: directive. Is this even possible? An alternative that is also acceptable is to keep skip_member as is, but to alter MethodDocumenter (or something else?) to ignore the automethod directive if the name is __init__, but not sure the best way to do that.

Why am I trying to do this? I'm working on a collaborative project so I can't remove the automethod directives, but I want an automated way to show all documentation including private/hidden methods. (So we would have 2 documentations: 1 for consumers and one for developers in essence) Removing the automethod directive would mean that the consumer version would now have more info than needed, so I don't want to remove those, but by not removing those, when I try and run the sphinx documentation, I'm getting a bunch of duplicate methods and so I need some way to suppress either the ones being included from automethod or from the skip_method way.
Edit:
Something that maybe wasn't clear in the above. I could technically use :no-index: to have the error not appear, but then the method gets duplicated (shows up twice in the docs).
.. automethod:: __init__
    :no-index:

When I try and look at the options variable in skip_member, I get a dictionary, but the only option showing up is members. In addition, the what is coming back as class which seems weird? I would have assumed it would come back as method since we're doing automethod?

I don't understand why you can't simply remove the automethod directives. You say that you work on a "collaborative project". Why does that matter?

I mention this in the paragraph. I technically could remove the automethod directive, but I would need some way to have a switch so that the __init__ in class A always shows up and the __init__ in class B only shows up if some parameter is set. (What skip_member is doing). If there is some way to do this by replacing the automethod directive, that's also ok.

Being "collaborative" means that I'm not the only one working on the project. So since everyone is already used to using the automethod directive it's easier to pretend I can't change it. It's open source, so it's much harder to get people to stop using the automethod directive than to figure out a way around it.

To skip the __init__ method of the A class, you can use if obj.__qualname__ == "A.__init__": return True. Is that helpful?

I would prefer something automated for 2 reasons (1) There are hundreds of classes. So doing one at a time is going to make a mess and (2) In the future when someone adds an additional automethod, we'd have to always remember to go back and update this massive list.
